# Unable to autoload serializer using Grape Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers, grape-api, api-versioning

I'm building an API with:

- Ruby 2.2
- Rails 4.2.6
- grape-gem 0.16.2
- active_model_serializers-gem 0.10.2
- grape-active_model_serializers-gem (1.4 from master)

My JSON serializers work well until I try to introduce API Versioning as described here: https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-active_model_serializers

**Unversioned serializer:**

```
class SignupSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :comments, :pending
end
```

**Versioned serializer:**

```
module Mobile
  module V1
    class SignupSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id, :comments, :pending
    end
  end
end
```

The error message is:

LoadError (Unable to autoload constant SignupSerializer, expected /Users/username/GitHub/AppName/app/serializers/mobile/v1/signup_serializer.rb to define it):
  app/api/mobile/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  app/api/mobile/logger.rb:15:in`call'

**API Organization:**

[image]

**base.rb:**

```
require 'grape-swagger'

module Mobile
  class Dispatch < Grape::API
    mount Mobile::V1::Root
    mount Mobile::V2::Root
    format :json
    route :any, '*path' do
      Rack::Response.new({message: 'Not found'}.to_json, 404).finish
    end
    add_swagger_documentation
  end

  Base = Rack::Builder.new do
    use Mobile::Logger
    run Mobile::Dispatch
  end
end
```

**v1/root.rb:**

```
module Mobile
  module V1
    class Root < Dispatch
      format :json
      formatter :json, Grape::Formatter::ActiveModelSerializers
      version 'v1'
      default_error_formatter :json
      content_type :json, 'application/json'
      use ::WineBouncer::OAuth2

      rescue_from :all do |e|
        eclass = e.class.to_s
        message = "OAuth error: #{e.to_s}" if eclass.match('WineBouncer::Errors')
        status = case 
        when eclass.match('OAuthUnauthorizedError')
          401
        when eclass.match('OAuthForbiddenError')
          403
        when eclass.match('RecordNotFound'), e.message.match(/unable to find/i).present?
          404
        else
          (e.respond_to? :status) && e.status || 500
        end
        opts = { error: "#{message || e.message}" }
        opts[:trace] = e.backtrace[0,10] unless Rails.env.production?
        Rack::Response.new(opts.to_json, status, {
          'Content-Type' => "application/json",
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
          'Access-Control-Request-Method' => '*',
        }).finish
      end

      mount Mobile::V1::Me
      mount Mobile::V1::Events
      mount Mobile::V1::Signups

      route :any, '*path' do
        raise StandardError, 'Unable to find endpoint'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**api/v1/signup.rb:**

```
module Mobile
  module V1
    class Signups < Mobile::V1::Root
      include Mobile::V1::Defaults

      resource :signups, desc: 'Operations about the signups' do

        desc "Returns list of signups"
        oauth2 # This endpoint requires authentication

        get '/' do
          Signup.where(pending: false)
        end

      end

    end

  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem maintainers are working on an update for this issue. An update can be downloaded the repository:

https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-active_model_serializers/issues/55